# On/Off Switch AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sass, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create switch in angularJS.

I have setup directive with the switch though my example doesn't show it.

The API returns boolean but It seem that radio button changes it to string, therefore the first click takes the boolean and changes it and then nothing happends.

I think this is just the CSS more than the angularJS any suggestions how I can get passed it or make radio button flip between boolean instead of strings?

[Example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DAzjy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to do with the `radio inputs` but the easy way you can make your code work is:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxAze

All you have to do is bind this `ng-click` event to the switch container so that it toggles the state of the `emailNotification` property.

```
<div ng-click="user.emailNotification = !user.emailNotification" class="toggle-bg {{user.emailNotification}}">
      <span class="switch {{user.emailNotification}}"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was going for. Guess I wasn't thinking "angular" way.